# Can a git repository specify a minimum git version required?

Tags: git

Can a git repository specify a minimum git version required so that older git clients will refuse to check out a repository that requires a higher minimum version?

If so, how?

Comment: What is the reason of working with git like that, and what you want to avoid from? What if there's a tool that can work with git repositories not being git itself?

Comment: Why do you want to impose a minimum version?

Comment: Well, by 'version' in that case I rather mean like a version of the repository layout, not the version of a specific client software. For example, I'm pretty sure the very first git-scm client wouldn't be able to handle evey git repository that the latest version can generate (for example one that was initialized with --object-format=sha256)

Comment: @matthias_buehlmann Git uses a very simple objects and relationship model, so I don't really think it might change drastically from the very beginning. My latest git still reports `0` for `git config core.repositoryformatversion`.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/hash-function-transition/#_detailed_design seems to be able to shed some light on what you're asking: _The combination of setting core.repositoryFormatVersion=1 and populating extensions.* ensures that all versions of Git later than v0.99.9l will die instead of trying to operate on the SHA-256 repository, instead producing an error message._

Comment: core.repositoryformatversion - that's what I've been looking for, thank you!

Comment: maybe post this as an answer, so I can accept it. might be useful for others too.

Comment: Just a warning: `--object-format=sha256` is not for you if you have to ask this question. Don't use it. Definitely not for a repository that has value for you.

Comment: @matthias_buehlmann Thanks but I won't: 1) from your initial question it was not clear that you were talking about git repository layout; 2) I never got to play around with the format version 1, so I can't make expertise out of that; "oneliners" are not really permitted as answers at S.O.. However, I'm glad it could help you out.

Comment: @j6t why would you say that? While the feature is still considered ‚experimental‘, what‘s not clear yet is interoperability with sha1 repositories, but the sha256 part is rock solid

Comment: @matthias_buehlmann I say it because of the "experimental" tag.